# I can't do a simple calculator with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, calculator

i want to make a simple calculator that just sum two numbers

```js
var num1 = Number(document.getElementById("n1").value);
var num2 = Number(document.getElementById("n2").value);

function sum() {
  var result = num1 + num2;
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n1">
<input type="text" id="n2">
<button id="btn" onclick="sum();">Submit</button>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

when i run it and add two values and press the button it returns 0 in the console

Comment: num1 and num2 get set to a number, not a reference to the elements value. This means that their values don't change when you write something in the input. You have to do that assignment in the function itself

Comment: You've to move the variable declarations inside the function.

Comment: You probably need to put the 'var num1' and 'var  num2' lines inside your function before the 'var result' line....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code you retrieve values **before** they are changed by a user.

```js
var num1 = document.getElementById("n1");
var num2 = document.getElementById("n2");

function sum() {
  var result = Number(num1.value) + Number(num2.value);
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n1">
<input type="text" id="n2">
<button id="btn" onclick="sum();">Submit</button>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually storing the first value of the inputs, which defaults to 0.

Change the variables to references to the elements. Then access the values when the user presses the button.

```js
var num1 = document.getElementById("n1");
var num2 = document.getElementById("n2");

function sum() {
  var result = parseInt(num1.value) + parseInt(num2.value);
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n1">
<input type="text" id="n2">
<button id="btn" onclick="sum();">Submit</button>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the num1 and num2 variables into the sum function, because your script should read the num1 and num2 values each time you want to calculate the sum.

```
 function sum() {
      var num1 = Number(document.getElementById("n1").value);
      var num2 = Number(document.getElementById("n2").value);
      var result = num1 + num2;
      console.log(result);
    }
```